Spring Data Rest / openapi - Change serialization for collection in relation
Using

spring-data-rest-webmvc - to create apis from repos
openapi-generator-cli - to generate models in typescript

My Java models
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RepositoryRestResource
public class RespTemplateApi {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    String info;

    @NotNull
    String what;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    RespOccurrence occurrence;

    LocalDate lastExecutedAt;

}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RepositoryRestResource
public class RespBundleApi {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="bundle_id")
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    String what;

    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<RespTemplateApi> temps;

}

This is whats getting generated
export interface RespBundleApiRequestBody {
    /**
     * 
     * @type {number}
     * @memberof RespBundleApiRequestBody
     */
    'id'?: number;
    /**
     * 
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof RespBundleApiRequestBody
     */
    'what': string;
    /**
     * 
     * @type {Array<string>}
     * @memberof RespBundleApiRequestBody
     */
    'temps': Array<string>;
}

This is what i'm expecting to be generated
export interface RespBundleApi {
    /**
     * 
     * @type {number}
     * @memberof RespBundleApi
     */
    'id'?: number;
    /**
     * 
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof RespBundleApi
     */
    'what': string;
    /**
     * 
     * @type {Array<RespTemplateApi>}
     * @memberof RespBundleApi
     */
    'temps': Array<RespTemplateApi>;
}

How to generate model with "'temps': Array<RespTemplateApi>;" which later on I can use as REST API? Every endpoint also expecting RespBundleApiRequestBody instead of reusing already existing model RespBundleApi
